# Lazy Loading Image filename with spaces

Tags: load, lazy-evaluation

I am using a lazy loader for images and it works, but will not work when their is a space in the filename.  I have created a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V6RaR/2/).  Does anyone know how to update this code to insert %20 in the filename?  Or accept spaces somehow?  I am unsure how to accomplish this.

The jsFiddle loads this div,

```
<div id="layz" data-background="http://www.small-world.net/_borders/small_world_logo.gif">
</div>
```

but not this one,

```
<div id="layz" data-background="http://c1-preview.prosites.com/10426/wy/images/teeth with spaces.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: You might need to `urlencode` your urls if they have spaces in. Try replacing the spaces with `%20`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just used str_replace function in php to changes spaces in filenames to %20.  That worked just fine.  For some reason when I used urlencode the lazy loader didn't recognized the url.

Comment: I have similar issue, in my case the problem is '#' character in the filename, which probably should also be encoded.